# Convert DATE to UTCTicks for sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a database query that defines `DATE` values using ticks format and a `WHERE` clause that uses regular `DateTime` format, can query execution automatically convert to ticks format and return the correct results?

For example, as shown in the following sample code, when `UTCTicks` receives a regular date value as input, it's automatically converted to UTC ticks before the query runs:

```
where StartUTCTicks > 637212960000000000 and StartUTCTicks < 637345151990000000
```

Comment: [This](https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/converting-from-datetime-to-ticks-using-sql-server/) should get you going.

Comment: You'll be **MUCH** better off if you start keeping `DateTime` values instead of Ticks in the database column. Why? Because Sql Server already stores DateTime values in pretty much the same way, so they're no storage efficiency gain using ticks, but DateTime values also give you access to native date math and formatting functions, as well as better indexing support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert between dates and ticks using a couple of handy "constants":

```
declare @TicksPerDay as BigInt = 24 * 60 * 60 * Cast( 10000000 as BigInt );
declare @BaseDate as Date = '0001-01-01';
```

Some examples of usage:

```
select @TicksPerDay as TicksPerDay, @BaseDate as BaseDate;

select DateDiff( day, @BaseDate, GetUTCDate() ) * @TicksPerDay as TodayInUTCTicks;

select DateAdd( day, 637212960000000000 / @TicksPerDay, @BaseDate ) as SampleDate1,
  DateAdd( day, 637345151990000000 / @TicksPerDay, @BaseDate ) as SampleDate2;
```

In order to allow your `where` clause to use an index on `StartUTCTicks` you would want to convert the tick values to `date` values rather than the other way around:

```
where DateAdd( day, 637212960000000000 / @TicksPerDay, @BaseDate ) < StartUTCTicks and
  StartUTCTicks < DateAdd( day, 637345151990000000 / @TicksPerDay, @BaseDate );
```

Answer (score 1):

> query automatically convert that to ticks and brings results from DB

Yes, you can make this happen automatically. The way you do it is by storing the value as a `DateTime` column in the first place!

Sql Server already stores datetime values in an efficient binary format. *It does not store them as strings,* unless you were foolish enough to choose a varchar type. Therefore, the only thing you gain by trying to use ticks in Sql Server instead of DateTime values is pain from losing easy access to the built-in DateTime functions and indexing, including automatically treating certain literals in your SQL code as DateTime values.