# Convert DATE to UTCTicks for sql query date input

Tags: t-sql

I have created ssrs report where user can input date start and end parameter in this **format yyyy-mm-dd** as they are not aware of UTC Ticks. but the query that runs in the back to pull data requires UTC ticks to be inputted .  Here is query and how can i modify this query to input so converts user input date into UTC ticks before it runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all due respect to HABO as shown in  [Convert DATE to UTCTicks for sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015153/convert-date-to-utcticks-for-sql-query)

```
declare @TicksPerDay as BigInt = 24 * 60 * 60 * Cast( 10000000 as BigInt );
select DateDiff( day, '00010101', '2020-03-02' ) * @TicksPerDay as TodayInUTCTicks;
```

Comment: Thanks now i understand